# Cakephp - saveall() - What should the arrray look like?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to save a lot of data at once with the saveAll() method in cakephp 2. The problem is that I don't understand what the array that I'm passing to the saveAll() function should look like.

I have the following models:

```
Recipe:
hasMany: Recipeitem
hasAndBelongsToMany:Category

Category:
hasAndBelongsToMany: Recipe

Recipeitem:
belongsTo: Recipe
hasMany: Ingredient

Ingredient:
belongsTo: Grocery, Recipeitem

Grocery:
hasMany: Ingredient
```

**So if I would like to save a recipe with two recipeitems with two ingredients each, what should the array object that I'm passing to the saveAll function look like?**

This is what my array looks like at the moment:

```
Array
(
[Recipe] => Array
    (
        [title] => Mushroom pie
        [instructions] => Just mix it!
        [cooking_time] => 20
    )

[Category] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 3
            )

    )

[Recipeitem] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Recipeitem] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Crust
                        [order] => 0
                        [Ingredients] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Ingredient] => Array
                                            (
                                                [amount] => 2
                                                [unit] => dl
                                                [order] => 0
                                                [Grocery] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Butter
                                                        [description] => Butter
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    ),
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Ingredient] => Array
                                            (
                                                [amount] => 3
                                                [unit] => dl
                                                [order] => 1
                                                [Grocery] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Sugar
                                                        [description] => Sugar
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            ),
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Recipeitem] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Filling
                        [order] => 1
                        [Ingredients] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Ingredient] => Array
                                            (
                                                [amount] => 2
                                                [unit] => dl
                                                [order] => 0
                                                [Grocery] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Mushroom
                                                        [description] => Mushroom
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: [an article I wrote about it](http://www.pabloleanomartinet.com/cakephp-2-x-saving-and-validating-a-habtm-relation-example/) the other day.. might help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself now by reading the CakePHP cookbook a little better:

> Changed in version 2.1: You can now save deeper associated data as
>   well with setting $options['deep'] = true;

So for me this was all I needed:

```
$saveOptions['deep'] = true;
if ($this->Recipe->saveAll($this->request->data, $saveOptions )) {
```